# Spring Boot: Read Datasource properties from another property file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to configure a tomcat data source in Spring Boot, The properties of the database are stored in another property file (Say dbConnection.properties) with different keys.

For example

**dbConnection.properties:**

```
DATABASE_URL=SomeURL
DATABASE_USER=SomeUser
DATABASE_PASSWORD=SomePassword
```

From what I understand the properties related to a data source must be specified in **application.properties** as:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

How do I pass the values from dbConnection.properties to application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

***Property contributions can come from additional jar files on your classpath so you should not consider this an exhaustive list. It is also perfectly legit to define your own properties.***

so you can have your own property file and it should be in your classpath,

Inject property using `Value` annotation

`@Value("#{propFileName.propKeyName}")`

Comment: I will have to fall back to Bean configurations to do this, Is there any way that I can map entries from the outside property file to application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is override the Spring-Boot's Datasource default configuration. See the example above:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
   return DataSourceBuilder
    .create()
    .username("") // TODO: Get from properties
    .password("") // TODO: Get from properties
    .url("") // TODO: Get from properties
    .driverClassName("") // TODO: Get from properties
    .build();
}
```

In order to get from properties you can use the `@Value` annotation that @Saravana said you.

Answer (score 0):

@Manish Kothari... try this,create a configuration class with the annotations like 
@ConfigurationProperties.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:dbConnection.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigurationClass{

 //some code

}
```

and now it will call your DB properities... I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this
1.You can pass the property files from the command promopt

```
-Dspring.config.location=classpath:job1.properties,classpath:job2.properties
```

2.Way is to add @PropertySource annotation
public class AppConfig

```
    @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
    public class LoadDbProps{
      @value("${DATABASE_USER}")
      private String dbUserName;
      private String dbUserName; 
    }
```

Later you can set this  LoadDbProps to application.properties properties using @Bean configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me :

```
 @Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        Properties properties = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder =null;
        try {
        properties = new Properties();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);
        dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(properties.getProperty("url"));
        dataSourceBuilder.username(properties.getProperty("user"));
        dataSourceBuilder.password(properties.getProperty("password"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("CONFIG EXCEPTION :"+ex);
        }
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

refer below link for more details:

[https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/#:~:text=Spring%20boot%20allows%20defining%20datasource,a%20DataSource%20bean%20for%20us](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/#:%7E:text=Spring%20boot%20allows%20defining%20datasource,a%20DataSource%20bean%20for%20us).